# Heatmap 0 data values are not aligned properly

Tags: highcharts

If there is any data with 0 in the heatmap it is not aligned.

Set some data to 0 in the heatmap.  The data with value of 0 is not aligned.  Is there anything we can do to align it?

http://jsfiddle.net/yg0v13j6/

```js
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 40
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            title: null
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 320
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                style: {
                    textShadow: 'none',
                    HcTextStroke: null
                }
            }
        }]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in `4.0.4` version, fixed on master branch: http://jsfiddle.net/yg0v13j6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
format: '{point.value}',
```

to your dataLabels configuration and it will align the number properly.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by upgrading from version 4.0.1 to version 4.2.5. So the error must have been fixed somewhere between those two versions. But it is not merely a bug in 4.0.4 (as it has been claimed) since I also experienced the problem in version 4.0.1.

Matheus Baumgart's fix about adding a format key to the JSON did not work for me.